# CGIAR DEM + gdalwarp -- projection to Cartesian is not happening

Tags: dem, gdalwarp

I have downloaded a 30-by-30 tile from [image]

http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/srtmdata/

Then `gdalinfo` on the obtained single `*.tif`-file would yield

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: cut_n30e000.tif
       cut_n30e000.tif.aux.xml
Size is 36024, 36023
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (-0.010416618510297,60.009584059976817)
Pixel Size = (0.000833333353512,-0.000833333353512)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -0.0104166,  60.0095841) 
Lower Left  (  -0.0104166,  29.9904167) 
Upper Right (  30.0095841,  60.0095841) 
Lower Right (  30.0095841,  29.9904167) 
Center      (  14.9995837,  45.0000004) 
Band 1 Block=36024x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=-444.000 Max=4783.000 
  Minimum=-444.000, Maximum=4783.000, Mean=348.628, StdDev=398.861
  NoData Value=-32768
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=4783
    STATISTICS_MEAN=348.62818252965
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-444
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=398.86067773429
```

So far so good. So I would try to project this onto a 2D plane, as follows:
`gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=44.00 +lon_0=15.00 +units=m +no_defs' cut_n30e000.tif result_europe.tmerc.tif`.
After this operation, `result_europe.tmerc.tif` is supposed to be represented
with respect to a Cartesian system of coordinates.
But I was surprised to find out that the lat/lon system persists:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: result_europe.tmerc.tif
Size is 36024, 36023
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["WGS84",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",44],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-0.010416618510297,60.009584059976817)
Pixel Size = (0.000833333353512,-0.000833333353512)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -0.0104166,  60.0095841) ( 15d 0' 0.00"E, 44d 0' 1.94"N)
Lower Left  (  -0.0104166,  29.9904167) ( 15d 0' 0.00"E, 44d 0' 0.97"N)
Upper Right (  30.0095841,  60.0095841) ( 15d 0' 1.35"E, 44d 0' 1.94"N)
Lower Right (  30.0095841,  29.9904167) ( 15d 0' 1.35"E, 44d 0' 0.97"N)
Center      (  14.9995837,  45.0000004) ( 15d 0' 0.67"E, 44d 0' 1.46"N)
Band 1 Block=36024x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-32768
```

Why the original lat/lon bounds are still there? I.e. what was wrong with my `gdalwarp` command above?

Comment: What are you specifying as -s_srs? It's not defined in your *from* info.

Comment: yes that's cruddy, the files don't have the CRS inside - add `-s_srs "+init=epsg:4326" ` to your gdalwarp call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just re-stating the answers provided by @MichaelStimson and @mdsummer:
`gdalwarp -s_srs '+init=epsg:4326' -t_srs '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=44.00 +lon_0=15.00 +units=m' cut_n30e000.tif result_europe.tmerc.tif` will do the job.
After this, `gdalinfo` gives the proper:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: result_europe.tmerc.tif
Size is 36696, 43220
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["WGS84",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",44],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-1456758.150925980880857,1876581.142161503667012)
Pixel Size = (79.393568841911133,-79.393568841911133)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-1456758.151, 1876581.142) ( 10d15'41.62"W, 58d20'50.81"N)
Lower Left  (-1456758.151,-1554808.903) (  0d 7' 0.41"E, 29d 8'47.69"N)
Upper Right ( 1456668.251, 1876581.142) ( 40d15'36.63"E, 58d20'51.87"N)
Lower Right ( 1456668.251,-1554808.903) ( 29d52'56.37"E, 29d 8'48.06"N)
Center      (     -44.950,  160886.119) ( 14d59'57.93"E, 45d26'51.99"N)
Band 1 Block=36696x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-32768
```