# CGIAR DEM converted to XYZ consists of Nodata only

Tags: dem

I have a 30-by-30 tile from [image: http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/srtmdata/]

http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/srtmdata/

Later I pre-process as outlined in the previous question [CGIAR DEM + gdalwarp -- projection to Cartesian is not happening](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317722/cgiar-dem-gdalwarp-projection-to-cartesian-is-not-happening)
(see the question and the answer therein).

After this, I run `gdal_translate -of XYZ result_europe.tmerc.tif europe.xyz`,
but `head europe.xyz` yields

```
1455914.01239279192 -1554769.20640147454 -32768
1455993.40596163366 -1554769.20640147454 -32768
1456072.79953047587 -1554769.20640147454 -32768
1456152.19309931761 -1554769.20640147454 -32768
1456231.58666815935 -1554769.20640147454 -32768
1456310.98023700155 -1554769.20640147454 -32768
1456390.37380584329 -1554769.20640147454 -32768
1456469.7673746855 -1554769.20640147454 -32768
1456549.16094352724 -1554769.20640147454 -32768
1456628.55451236898 -1554769.20640147454 -32768
```

Same story with `tail`. So I presume all of them are missing values.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the coordinate system that you are means that both in the beginning and in the end of the file you will have lots and lots of nodata values. Now, the way that the gdal version of the XYZ format works means that -32768 is the value chosen for nodata. With that in mind, you'll have to remove all those nodata values, which is a bit of work.
How you go about removing those lines with nodata is going to depend a lot on which tools you are comfortable with.

Comment: Currently I am running something like this: `cat europe.xyz | sed '/\s\+-32768$/d' > europe_curated.xyz`. So this is not unusual, then, to have those `nodata` values after all the transformations.